# how to delete files from a folder according to date

Tags: asp.net, file

```
private void DeleteFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\test");
    var files = di.GetFiles();
    var maxFile = files.Max(r => r.Length);

    foreach (FileInfo file in files.Where(r => r.Length < maxFile))
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DeleteFiles();
}
```

in this code i delete file according to size now what i want is i want to delete file according to date also 
for ex: suppose i create 5 file yesterday and 5 file today now i want to delete all the files except who's size is largest for both days how can i do that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you look at the properties of the file (FileInfo) and build your delete routines with the properties CreationTime and Length in mind...

Answer (score 0):

you can get the time like this

```
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"c:\file.txt");
DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\file.txt");
DateTime lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(@"c:\file.txt");
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-creation-modification-time/

also compare the time using `DateTime.Compare`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

Comment: how to combine it with size and delete function

Comment: @amitesh use the compare and use an AND (&&) operator

Answer (score 0):

You can select files based on [`FileInfo.CreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx) property and then select those files like:

```
private void DeleteFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\test");
    var files = di.GetFiles();
    var maxFile = files.Max(r => r.Length);

    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var filesToBeDeleted = files.Where(r=> (r.Length < maxFile)  
                                         && (r.CreationTime >= startDate &&
                                             r.CreationTime <= endDate));

    foreach (FileInfo file in filesToBeDeleted)
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

You can make the selection based on other DateTime properties with FileInfo like, [LastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx), also you can specify your own start and end date for your criteria.

Comment: Errors :: Error 1 The name 'maxFile' does not exist in the current context E:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Amitesh\YMT\Default2.aspx.cs 32 60 E:\...\YMT\ Error 2 ) expected E:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Amitesh\YMT\Default2.aspx.cs 34 68 E:\...\YMT\

Comment: That was a suggested modification in your existing method, try now, I have pasted the complete method.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Did you specify the start date and end date correctly, the code above is just for example.

Comment: you mean to say i have to enter a particular date for it

Comment: can you give me an example so that i can set according to my self date format or you want me to add two calender on page to select date